# Grub2 not recognizing USB stick after update?

Tags: usb, arch-linux, grub2

I have a pretty basic ArchLinux setup in VirtualBox that I regularly copy over to a USB stick to boot on a real machine. It worked fine for the past few months, but after the last update (Oct 8th 2018) GRUB2 no longer recognizes my LUKS-encrypted system partition, when booting off the USB stick, and drops me into an emergency shell. Running `blkid` in that shell reveals that GRUB2 doesn't even recognize the USB stick it is loaded from.

Here is a little summary of things that work(ed) and that don't work suggesting that neither my computer nor my USB stick are the problem, but my Arch system:

```
                          |                      ArchLinux                      |  Fresh install of
                          |  before update  |  after update  | fresh reinstall  |   Ubuntu 18.04.1
--------------------------+-----------------+----------------+------------------+--------------------
Booting from virtual hard |     worked      |     works      |      works       |       works*
disk in VirtualBox        |                 |                |                  |
--------------------------+-----------------+----------------+------------------+--------------------
Booting from USB          |     worked      |  NOT WORKING   |   NOT WORKING    |       works*
in VirtualBox             |                 |                |                  |
--------------------------+-----------------+----------------+------------------+--------------------
Booting from USB          |     worked      |  NOT WORKING   |   NOT WORKING    |       works*
on a computer             |                 |                |                  |

* with and without full disk encryption (LVM on LUKS)
```

Naturally I tried to fix this by firing up the Arch-iso, mounting all the partitions (of the USB stick), `arch-chroot`ing into the system, checking `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` as well as `/etc/default/grub` and running `mkinitcpio -p linux` as well as `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Still not able to boot... I also tried overwriting the USB stick with the updated and still working system from the virtual hard disk, but with no luck either.

**Has anyone a clue as to what might be causing this behavior or any hint where I need to look for problems?** It can't be the disk encryption, because the system on the virtual hard disk still works after the update (and sadly I haven't got a backup from before the update).

---

**UPDATE:** Booting with the fallback initramfs works fine in all cases (vbox, usb in vbox, usb on machine). There might be some hooks missing in the mkinitcpio.conf.

---

Here are some specifics about my Arch system: It is an EFI system with a GPT formatted disk containing just two partitions, a 200 MiB FAT32 partition with GRUB2 on it and a 15.8 GiB LUKS container holding the ext4 system partition, no LVM involved. Here is a summary of the configuration files. If you need more, let me know.

```
# /etc/mkinitcpio.conf
[...]
HOOKS=(base udev autodetect keyboard keymap modconf block encrypt filesystems fsck)
[...]

# /etc/default/grub
[...]
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="cryptdevice=/dev/disk/by-uuid/UUID_OF_LUKS_CONTAINER:cryptosystem"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
[...]
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true
[...]
#GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y
[...]

# /boot/grub/grub.cfg
[...]
linux /vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=UUID_OF_FS_INSIDE_LUKS rw cryptdevice=/dev/disk/by-uuid/UUID_OF_LUKS_FS:cryptosystem quiet
[...]
```

Tags: usb, arch-linux, grub2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `autodetect` hook solves the problem, now I can boot the system without using the fallback image.